# ZK Framework rendering hidden buttons read by JAWS

Tags: zk, jaws-screen-reader

We're testing a site for JAWS usability and are having an issue with the listbox tag from the ZK framework. When ZK processes a listbox, it is rendering a < button > (in IE) or an < a > (in FireFox) after the table (see IE button output below). JAWS is reading the href attribute contents of this button (or link). Is there anyway to have ZK not render this button (or link) or possibly change some of it's attributes? I've been searching extensively for this but the solution is eluding me. Thanks for any help!!

```
<button class="z-focus-a" id="j4yPd0-a" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;" onclick="return false;" href="javascript:;"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`Clients.evalJavaScript`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/util/Clients.html#evalJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29) in the `onCreated` event handler of the listbox to execute some [zk-jQuery](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/jsdoc/_global_/jq.html) code to find and manipulate/delete the button. 
The jq command could look like this for deletion.

```
jq('button.z-focus-a').remove();
```

The code as it would be called in Java.

```
Clients.evalJavaScript("jq('button.z-focus-a').remove();");
```